# First time trying to create a draggable div in jQuery but it doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

The code in my eyes has nothing wrong with it it should have worked but didn't. Why is the div I created not draggable?

```html
</html>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="drag">
        <p>content</p>
    </div>
    
    <style>
        #drag {
            background-color: rgb(89, 0, 255);
            height: 60px;
            width: 150px;
        }
    </style>

    <script>
        (document).ready(()=>{
            $(function () {
                $("#drag").draggable();
            });               
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: make it `position:absolute` ?

Comment: You can use the HTML5 Drag and Drop API. Set ```draggable=true``` on that elemen to make an object draggable. You can find an example here https://web.dev/drag-and-drop/?gclid=Cj0KCQiAuvOPBhDXARIsAKzLQ8HEKNXvkm3_xfWtP_r1QXdZupYrMZ3vTc_gCE1AoDJBnHOzfRAvJH8aAhaOEALw_wcB#listening-for-dragging-events

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should include the following references in the project:

- [jquery-ui.css](https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css)
- [jquery-.js](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js)
- [jquery-ui.js](https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/jquery-ui.js)

Additionally you have to define the `<style>` element inside the `<head></head>` block.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <!-- The following references have been added to the project. -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>    
    <!-- The <style> element has been moved inside the <head> block. -->
    <style>
        #drag {
            background-color: rgb(89, 0, 255);
            height: 60px;
            width: 150px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="drag">
      <p>content</p>
  </div>
  
  <script>
    $(document).ready(() => {
     $(function () {
        $("#drag").draggable();
       });      
     })
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, your code is so nice that it works perfectly with the code of my upcoming new website. But, before launching the website, I have a few questions? Can I use (after some random modifications) your code without copyright issues? If it is yes, how do I acknowledge/cite/attribute the idea of this code? I know that StackOverflow is not open source. That is why I am asking this? Thanks.

Comment: [This link](https://empirical-software.engineering/blog/so-snippets-in-gh-projects) contains information about the license. I think it is enough to share some information about the code to be used.

Comment: Thanks for telling me. So, I need to mention links to this question id, this answer id, your profile id, and the id of this whole page. Also, do you know how to modify this code so that it works for touch screen mobile phones? Thanks again.

Comment: You can easily do it using the [@media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries).